# Integral involving an absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, absolute-value

How can I evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\left|\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\right|\space\text{d}t=\left|\hat{\text{u}}\right|\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\left|\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\right|\space\text{d}t$$

Where all variables are real except $\text{s}$ because $\text{s}\in\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\omega=1$, $\varphi=0$. Then we write
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}|\sin(t)|dt=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\pi}e^{-st}|\sin(t)|dt$$
Now if $n\geq 0$ we have
$$\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\pi}e^{-st}|\sin(t)|dt=\int_0^{\pi}e^{-s(u+n\pi)}|\sin(u)|du=e^{-sn\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{-su}\sin(u)du$$
The integral is standard and can be computed using integration by parts or complex numbers and gives
$$\int_0^{\pi}e^{-su}\sin(u)du=\dfrac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{1+s^2}$$
hence
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}|\sin(t)|dt=\dfrac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{1+s^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-sn\pi}=\dfrac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{1+s^2}\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-\pi s}}$$
according to the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: The problem is you can not assume what you did in the first place.

Comment: I've to let them both be variable.